# Unreadable issue for local htm table file using "htmltab" function in r

Tags: r, html-table

I've tried to read the local htm table file stored on my desktop using "htmltab" function, but I could not.
And an error message appeared on the console as follows:

> Neither  nor  information found. Taking first table row for the header. If incorrect, specifiy header argument.
>   Warning message:
>   In readChar(doc, file.info(doc)$size) :
>     can only read in bytes in a non-UTF-8 MBCS locale

The contents of my htm table file are attached below.
Please let me know how you can respond to this issue.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Sun Time Table from Sanalyst 3.0 </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=ks_c_5601-1987">
<BODY>
<H1>"104동"의 일조시간표</H1>
<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=1>
<TH rowspan=2>행</TH><TH rowspan=2>열</TH><TH HEIGHT=27>총일조시간</TH><TH HEIGHT=27>연속일조시간</TH><TH>일조시간그래프</TH><TH rowspan=2>총일조<br>만족 여부</TH><TH rowspan=2>연속일조<br>만족 여부</TH><TH rowspan=2>일조<br>만족 여부</TH><tr><TH HEIGHT=25 ALIGN=CENTER><font size='2'>08시~16시</font></TH><TH HEIGHT=25 ALIGN=CENTER><font size='2'>09시~15시</font></TH><TD><IMG SRC="./104동.files/header.emf" ALIGN=LEFT>　</TD></tr><TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image0.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:12:48</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:12:48</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image1.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:11:30</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:11:30</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image2.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:09:29</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:09:29</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image3.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image4.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:12:48</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:12:48</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image5.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:11:30</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:11:30</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image6.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:09:29</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:09:29</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image7.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image8.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:12:48</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:12:48</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image9.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:11:30</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:11:30</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image10.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:25:46</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:16:41</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image11.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image12.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:12:48</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:12:48</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image13.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:13:42</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:13:42</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image14.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:34:54</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:34:54</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image15.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>5</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image16.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>5</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:15:42</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:15:42</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image17.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>5</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:26:53</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:26:53</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image18.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>5</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:36:38</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:36:38</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image19.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>6</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image20.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>6</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:20:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:20:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image21.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>6</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:26:53</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:26:53</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image22.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>6</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:52:32</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:52:32</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image23.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>7</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image24.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>7</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:20:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:20:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image25.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>7</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:34:51</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:34:51</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image26.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>7</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >01:02:17</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >01:02:17</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image27.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>8</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image28.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>8</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:26:24</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:26:24</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image29.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>8</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:44:44</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:44:44</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image30.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>8</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >01:28:49</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >01:04:31</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image31.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>9</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>1</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:05:55</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image32.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>9</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>2</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:36:40</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:36:40</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image33.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>9</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>3</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >01:15:04</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >00:55:21</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image34.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN = RIGHT>9</TD><TD ALIGN = RIGHT>4</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >02:24:50</TD><TD ALIGN = CENTER BGCOLOR = #dcdcdc >01:19:02</TD><TD WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=30><IMG SRC="./104동.files/image35.emf" ALIGN=CENTER></TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
<TD Align=center>X</TD>
</TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```